# I want two stacked barchart with different color Java(JSF) code is given but only one colour is showing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to show bar chart with different colour but only one colour showing. should I use a function which will return two arraylist or only one return is enough.

[image]

```
public BarChartModel getBcmMarineSH() {
    
    BarChartSeries FY = new BarChartSeries();
    BarChartSeries F2 = new BarChartSeries();
   
    String txtFy = "";
    bcmMarine = new BarChartModel();
    stacked = new BarChartModel();
    try {
        ArrayList vec = new ArrayList();
        vec.add(getTrade_Type());
        ArrayList parm = new ArrayList();
        parm.add(vec);
        DaoReq[] req = new DaoReq[1];
        req[0] = new DaoReq();
        req[0].setMethodSignature("225"); // getChaPdb()   //getMarinePdbBarChartSM
        req[0].setParamCount(1);
        req[0].setParamList(parm);
        DaoRes res[] = (DaoRes[]) aPosCdbReg.PerformTask(req);
        if (res[0].isStatus()) {
            ArrayList aRes = (ArrayList) res[0].getResult();
            //FY.setLabel((String) aRes.get(0));                             ///  problem starts here
        //  FY.setLabel("Foreign Bill"); 
            FY.setData((Map<Object, Number>) aRes.get(0));  //Map
            //ArrayList aReq =(ArrayList) res[1].getResult();
            F2.setData((Map<Object,Number>) aRes.get(1));
            
            
        } else {
            System.out.println(res[0].getMessage());
            System.out.println(res[1].getMessage());
            
        }           
        //
        bcmMarine.addSeries(FY);
        bcmMarine.setSeriesColors("FF0066");
        
        
        bcmMarine.setTitle("Marine Bills (In Lakhs)");
        bcmMarine.setStacked(true);
        bcmMarine.setAnimate(true);
        bcmMarine.setShowPointLabels(true);
        bcmMarine.setShowDatatip(false);
        bcmMarine.setLegendPosition("e");
        bcmMarine.setLegendCols(1);
        bcmMarine.getAxis(AxisType.X).setLabel("Financial Year");
        bcmMarine.addSeries(F2);
        bcmMarine.setSeriesColors("42EFF5");
        //Axis yAxis = bcmCheImport.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        //yAxis.setMin(0);
        //yAxis.setMax(1000);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        System.out.println(th.getMessage());
    }
    
    return bcmMarine;
}
```

Comment: You are just re-setting the series color as *42EFF5*.  Set all the color at once . EG: `bcmMarine.setSeriesColors("FF0066,42EFF5");`.  If there are more series than the no of colors then colors will repeat.

Comment: how can I extend those. one's length is more another's is less how to extend graph.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by extending . Your first series will take the first color , the second series takes the second color and so on.

Comment: extending means support year 2013's total is 5000 and 6000 I want it stacked but problem is both bar starts with x axis (horizontally ), I want let 5000 complete then 6000 will be stacked above 5000 not from bottom line (x axis). I hope you get the point.

Comment: For that use `StackbarChart`. I think you should be able to find some documentation regarding that on the in PrimeFaces site itself.